# Why are Float and Double different in the case of adding 0.1 and 0.2?

Tags: haskell

Can someone explain why

```
(0.1::Float) + (0.2::Float) == (0.3::Float)
```

while

```
(0.1::Double) + (0.2::Double) /= (0.3::Double)
```

To my knowledge Double is supposed to be more precise. Is there something about Float I should know about?

Answer (score 16):

The first thing to realize is that when you enter `0.1::Double` and ghci prints `0.1` back, it's only an "illusion:"

```
Prelude Data.Ratio> 0.1::Double
0.1
```

Why is that an illusion? Because the number `0.1` is actually not precisely representable as a floating point number! This is true for both `Float` and `Double`. Observe:

```
Prelude Data.Ratio> toRational (0.1::Float)
13421773 % 134217728
Prelude Data.Ratio> toRational (0.1::Double)
3602879701896397 % 36028797018963968
```

So, in reality, these numbers are indeed "close" to the actual real number `0.1`, but neither is precisely `0.1`. How close are they? Let's find out:

```
Prelude Data.Ratio> toRational (0.1::Float) - (1%10)
1 % 671088640
Prelude Data.Ratio> toRational (0.1::Double) - (1%10)
1 % 180143985094819840
```

As you see, `Double` is indeed a lot more precise than `Float`; the difference between the representation of `0.1` as a `Double` and the actual real-number `0.1` is a lot smaller. But neither is precise.

So, indeed the `Double` addition is a lot more precise, and should be preferred over the `Float` version. The confusing equality you see is nothing but the weird effect of rounding. The results of `==` should *not* be trusted in the floating-point land. In fact, there are many floating point numbers `x` such that `x == x + 1` holds. Here's one example:

```
Prelude> let x = -2.1474836e9::Float
Prelude> x == x + 1
True
```

A good read on floating-point representation is the classic [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know about Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), which explains many of these quirky aspects of floating-point arithmetic.

Also note that this behavior is not unique to  Haskell. Any language that uses [IEEE754 Floating-point arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) will behave this way, which is the standard implemented by modern microprocessors.

Comment: I personally try to avoid using the term "floating point number". Floating point representations don't really look a whole lot like numbers when you start looking at the math. Types like `Int` and `Word` are certainly used as approximations to `Integer` and `Natural`, but they are themselves perfectly law-abiding commutative rings. Floating point representations, on the other hand, have virtually no nice properties: neither addition nor multiplication is associative, and multiplication doesn't distribute over addition.

Answer (score 8):

`Double` is indeed more precise. And yes, there is something you should know about floating point representations in general: you have to be very careful about how you use them! `==` is generally unlikely to actually be useful. You're generally going to want to compare floating point representations using more specialized functions, or at least check if the representation lies within some range rather than whether it has a certain value according to the built-in approximation.